# (error) ERR unknown command 'touch' on Redis for Windows

Tags: windows, redis, hiredis

I have currently installed Redis for Windows, when I run Redis-cli all the simple commands (set, get, hset, hget etc.) work. However the command 'touch' doesn't work and I get the error in the title. I am also trying to build Redis-plus-plus on windows and am receiving the same error when I try to run the given tests. Wondering if anyone has also had this problem and managed to fix it?